# Sharepoint 2010 Calendar problem

Tags: master-page, calendar

I have problem with my custom master page and calendar.
When I apply my custom Master Page calendar doesn't work and shows following error:

http://screencast.com/t/HasSqkjFoN4x

But when I use standard Master Page everything is ok, can anyone help me?
Or just give me idea how can I figure out error?

And my problem was described here http://startermasterpages.codeplex.com/discussions/218554

Answer (score 1):

So  probably it will be useful for someone.
The problem was that PlaceHolderMain wasn't included to container with id w4-workspace

Correct variant:

```
<div id="s4-workspace">
      <asp:contentplaceholder id="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server" />
</div>
```